# Problem styling list items

Tags: css, list, border, html-lists

I'm trying to style an ordered list that seemed quite simple but apparently is harder than I thought, what I need to do is to separate every item with a white border below, the problem is the the "bullet" or "list number" is not part of the `li` element so the border gets placed below the text only, here's an image of what I mean:

http://www.diigo.com/item/image/1j40h/5eni

I'm trying to find a way to make the bottom border span across the whole border but I haven't been able to, I though about adding a verticaly repeated background to the `ol` but if the text takes more than one line it won't work, my last resort was to use a `ul` without bullets and have the user type the number himself that what it'd be part of the `li` but this doesn't sound very user friendly :(

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `list-style-position` CSS property for your `ol` element:

```
ol
{
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

It will make your bullets part of the displayed list item content. This is all in accordance with CSS 2.1 specification ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position )